# Javascript - Adding text and create moving border interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this [page](http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/timer/practice-shots.html) with the help stack overflow guys. There are three minor issues which I couldn't fix. I'd like help from you.

1. In this link you can see a countdown timer. I need to add a text "Go" after number .
2. You can see a counter glow border ( For now its blue color ). Can we add a moving border effect for that? Eg https://codepen.io/vishwakarma02/full/wOVYWy
3. Sometimes the the border showing just behind the text "Practice shot". That shouldn't be like that.

Can you guys please check and give solutions. I have shared my code here. Thanks :)

```
    var timeLeft = 3;
    var videoCounter = 2;
    var videoText = 2;
    var elem = document.querySelector('.countdown-content__count');
    var timerId;

    function countdown() {
      if (timeLeft == 0) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeOut();
        $(".video-wrapper span").fadeOut();
        var playPromise = $("#video")[0].play();
      } else {
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
        timeLeft--;
      }
    }

    function practiceShot(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".countdown-content__head").slideUp(1000, function(){
              $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
                  opacity: 0,
                  display: 'inline-block'     
              }).animate({opacity:1},600);
              timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
              countdown();
            });
          }, 2000);
    }
    practiceShot();
    document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended', function() {
        if (videoCounter == 0) {
            return;
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName("countdown-content__head")[0].innerHTML = "<span>Practice Shot </span>" + videoText;
        videoText++;
        videoCounter--;
        timeLeft = 3;
        elem.innerHTML = "";
        $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeIn();
        $(".video-wrapper span").fadeIn();
        $(".countdown-content__head").slideDown(1000, function(){
              $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
                  opacity:1,
                  display: 'inline-block'     
              }).animate({opacity:0},600);
        });
        practiceShot();
    }, false);


     <div class="practice-shot-screen full-screen-height">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <span class="video-wrapper">
                      <video id="video" muted>
                        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                      </video>
                      <span></span>
                    </span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <div class="practice-shot-image">
                     <img alt="" src="images/practice-image.jpg">
                 </div>              
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="countdown-content">
               <div class="v-align-container">
                  <div class="v-align-grid">
                        <div class="countdown-content__head">                        
                              <!-- <strong> <img alt="" src="images/hd-border.png"> </strong>         -->
                              <span>PRACTICE SHOT 1</span> 
                              <!-- PRACTICE SHOT 1  -->
                              <!-- <strong> <img alt="" src="images/hd-border.png"> </strong> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="countdown-content__timer">


                        <!--test-->



                        <!--test-->


                          <span class="countdown-content__count"></span>
                        </div>
                  </div>   
               </div>

            </div>

          </div><!--practice-shot-screen-->



Css : 

.practice-shot-screen {
    position: relative;
}

.practice-shot-screen .row {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.practice-shot-screen [class^="col-"] {
    padding: 0;
}

.practice-shot-screen .v-align-container {
    position: relative;
}

.practice-shot-screen .video-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.video-wrapper span {
  content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 3000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.practice-shot-screen .video-wrapper video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    object-fit: cover;
}



.practice-shot-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.practice-shot-image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}


.countdown-content {
    max-width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    margin: auto;
}



.countdown-content__head {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 85px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}






.countdown-content__head::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 147px;
    width: 770px;
    background: url(../images/hd-border.png) no-repeat; 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size:contain; 
}

.countdown-content__head::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 147px;
    width: 770px;
    background: url(../images/hd-border.png) no-repeat; 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size:contain; 
}


.countdown-content__timer {
    font-family: 'beonwebfont';
    font-size: 320px;
    color: #ea3323;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #ea3323;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ea3323;
    width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;

    border-color: #467fff; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #467fff; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #467fff; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #467fff; 

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  opacity: 0;
}



.countdown-content__timer > span {
    display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.countdown-content__timer video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I have added html and css here : https://jsfiddle.net/Coder95/w5h4n9cq/

Comment: Please share your knowledge.

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS here along with your javascript

Comment: Yeah give me a sec :)

Comment: Can you please check this : https://jsfiddle.net/Coder95/w5h4n9cq/ ?

Comment: ADd your html and css HERE in your question (edit your question and add it to your question)

Comment: I have added all the code in my question.

Comment: Is there any solutions?

Comment: @Anjali Try not to spam users asking for a response. They'll reply if/when they have time.